# Maximum Weighted coverage approximation algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, combinatorics, set-cover

I am looking for an algorithm similar to the [unweighted maximum coverage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-coverage-problem/). However, I have been unable to find a similar algorithm for the weighted version.

How should I modify the algorithm above to take into account the weighted version whereby each element is weighted and would the approximation ratio of $(1 - 1/e)$ still hold for the weighted version ?

Comment: The Wikipedia page answers your question I think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem. Summary: the answer is yes, the greedy algorithm still works (now considering the weights, of course).

Comment: hey thanks for the link. I did see the wikipedia page before but I only noticed the linear program formulation of the problem which did not tell me how to solve. I am not able to find any academic materials on the mathematical proofs / approximation ratio for the weighted maximum coverage version

Answer (score 1):

If you check more closely, the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) points to the paper: [An analysis of approximations for maximizing submodular set functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01588971).

The paper proves that $(1-1/e)$ approximation holds in general for any objective function $f$ that is monotone and submodular. You can also find a formal statement in [Exercise 2.10 of the Book "The Design of Approximation Algorithms"](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf#page=60).

It is easy to see that the objective function of the weighted maximum coverage problem is monotone and submodular. Let $E$ be the given set of element. Each element $e_i \in E$ has weight $w_i$. Let $S = \{S_1,\dotsc,S_m\}$ be the collection of subsets of $E$, i.e., $S_j \subseteq E$ for each $j \in \{1,\dotsc,m\}$.

Let $A \subseteq S$ be any subcollection of subsets of $E$.
Let $f(A)$ denote the value of subcollection $A$: the sum of the weights of all the elements covered by sets in $A$. That is, $f(A) = \sum_{e_i \in \bigcup \{S_j \in A\} } w_i$.

1. $f$ is monotone since for any subcollections $A \subseteq B \subseteq S$, $f(A) \leq f(B)$.
2. $f$ is submodular since for any subcollections $A,B \subseteq S$, $f(A) + f(B) \geq f(A \cup B) + f(A \cap B)$.

The proof of both the above statements is easy; leaving those steps to you.
Thus, the standard greedy algorithm gives $(1-1/e)$-approximation for the weighted maximum coverage problem. You may find reading [Section 2.5 of the Book "The Design of Approximation Algorithms"](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf#page=47) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !